# the trait `NonAggregate` is not implemented for xxx when using rust diesel

Tags: rust, rust-diesel

I generate the shema from postgresql using this command:

```
diesel migration run
```

Then build this rust project using cargo build, shows error like this:

```
280 | / table! {
281 | |     rss_sub_source (id) {
282 | |         id -> Int8,
283 | |         sub_url -> Varchar,
...   |
316 | |     }
317 | | }
    | |_^ the trait `SelectableExpression<rss_sub_source::table>` is not implemented for `(rss_sub_source::columns::id, rss_sub_source::columns::sub_url, rss_sub_source::columns::created_time, rss_sub_source::columns::updated_time, rss_sub_source::columns::sub_status, rss_sub_source::columns::rss_type, rss_sub_source::columns::standard_type, rss_sub_source::columns::standard_version, rss_sub_source::columns::cron, rss_sub_source::columns::trigger_count, rss_sub_source::columns::next_trigger_time, rss_sub_source::columns::sub_name, rss_sub_source::columns::last_trigger_time, rss_sub_source::columns::tags, rss_sub_source::columns::source_url, rss_sub_source::columns::sub_type, rss_sub_source::columns::intro, rss_sub_source::columns::remark, rss_sub_source::columns::title_hash, rss_sub_source::columns::failed_count, rss_sub_source::columns::lang, rss_sub_source::columns::frequency_month, rss_sub_source::columns::reputation, rss_sub_source::columns::rep_lastest_refresh_time, rss_sub_source::columns::scrapy_take_time, rss_sub_source::columns::follower, rss_sub_source::columns::censor_status, rss_sub_source::columns::etag, rss_sub_source::columns::last_modified, rss_sub_source::columns::editor_pick, rss_sub_source::columns::fav_icon_url, rss_sub_source::columns::dynamic_interval, rss_sub_source::columns::local_icon_url, rss_sub_source::columns::creator)`
    |
note: required by a bound in `diesel::Table::AllColumns`
   --> /Users/xiaoqiangjiang/.cargo/registry/src/mirrors.ustc.edu.cn-61ef6e0cd06fb9b8/diesel-1.4.8/src/query_source/mod.rs:62:22
```

why would this happen? what should I do to fix it? This is the rust shema code generate by diesel about this table:

```
table! {
    rss_sub_source (id) {
        id -> Int8,
        sub_url -> Varchar,
        created_time -> Int8,
        updated_time -> Int8,
        sub_status -> Int2,
        rss_type -> Varchar,
        standard_type -> Varchar,
        standard_version -> Varchar,
        cron -> Varchar,
        trigger_count -> Int4,
        next_trigger_time -> Nullable<Timestamp>,
        sub_name -> Varchar,
        last_trigger_time -> Nullable<Timestamptz>,
        tags -> Nullable<Array<Int4>>,
        source_url -> Nullable<Varchar>,
        sub_type -> Nullable<Varchar>,
        intro -> Nullable<Varchar>,
        remark -> Nullable<Varchar>,
        title_hash -> Nullable<Varchar>,
        failed_count -> Int4,
        lang -> Nullable<Varchar>,
        frequency_month -> Nullable<Int4>,
        reputation -> Nullable<Int4>,
        rep_lastest_refresh_time -> Nullable<Int8>,
        scrapy_take_time -> Nullable<Int4>,
        follower -> Nullable<Int8>,
        censor_status -> Nullable<Int4>,
        etag -> Nullable<Varchar>,
        last_modified -> Nullable<Varchar>,
        editor_pick -> Nullable<Int4>,
        fav_icon_url -> Nullable<Varchar>,
        dynamic_interval -> Int4,
        local_icon_url -> Nullable<Varchar>,
        creator -> Int8,
    }
}
```

I have enable the large table by config the diesel like this:

```
diesel = { version = "1.4.7", features = ["postgres","32-column-tables"] }
```

but still not work.

Comment: Are you 100% sure that all your dependencies in `Cargo.toml` are have versions that are compatible with each other? Make sure you've done that and then run `cargo update`.

Comment: I am sure, now I just generate some table by config the diesel filter to solve this problem, I think it may because some big table problem. @Coder-256

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As explicitly spelled out in the documentation of the [`table!`](https://docs.diesel.rs/1.4.x/diesel/macro.table.html) macro:

> By default this allows a maximum of 32 columns per table. You can increase this limit to 64 by enabling the 64-column-tables feature. You can increase it to 128 by enabling the 128-column-tables feature. You can decrease it to 16 columns, which improves compilation time, by disabling the default features of Diesel. Note that enabling 64 column tables or larger will substantially increase the compile time of Diesel.

I count 34 columns for this table, so just enabling the `32-column-tables` does not add the necessary trait impls.